# Loop over a filename pattern in csh

Tags: for-loop, csh

The following bash `for` loop iterates over every file in a directory, moving it to a new location:

```
for file in *.com; do mv $file /home/Scratch/$file; done
```

What would be the equivalent for the C shell?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you get any errors or wrong results when you tried to convert it to csh syntax?

Comment: So you mean _"I have this bash code, what is the equivalent in csh?"_. Please edit the question because it's not clear at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot have a one line for loop in C-shell scripting. The best you can do is create a script file, if you commonly use it.

```
foreach file (*.com)
  mv $file /home/Scratch/$file
end
```